# Implement abstract properties without redefining __init__ in child

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, abstract-class, abc

I am learning the `abc` module and was wondering if what I want to do is possible.

Essentially, every child I make of the base class should have the SAME exact `__init__`. The base class will have a few abstract properties that will need to be defined by the child. I would to define those abstract properties without having to rewrite the entire `__init__` every time.

Example:

I initially tried something like this

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class test(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
       pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

class prop_ex(test):

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return "THIS WORKS"
```

```
>>> from abc_tests import prop_ex
>>> blah = prop_ex()
>>> blah.prop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'prop_ex' object has no attribute 'prop'
```

it didn't work.

Then I tried

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class test(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = prop

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

class prop_ex(test):
    prop = "THIS WORKS"

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop
```

Test

```
>>> from abc_tests import prop_ex
>>> blah = prop_ex()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "abc_tests.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.prop = prop
NameError: name 'prop' is not defined
```

No good either, so then I tried

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class test(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

class prop_ex(test):
    self.prop = "THIS WORKS"

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop
```

test

```
>>> from dunder_tests import prop_ex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "abc_tests.py", line 39, in <module>
    class prop_ex(test):
  File "abc_tests.py", line 40, in prop_ex
    self.prop = "THIS WORKS"
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

For the last one if you set a breakpoint in `__init__` of the parent and do a `dir(self)` you'll see `'prop'` in it.

```
>>> blah = prop_ex()
> abc_tests.py(14)__init__()
-> self.prop = prop
(Pdb) dir(self)
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', 'prop']
```

So I thought that would work.

Edit:

I see I am completely over complicating this. I could have simply did

```
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod

class test(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

class prop_ex(test):

    prop = "THIS WORKS"
```

Is there an issue with doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly summized, the most straight-forward solution would be to define an `abstractproperty` and simply let the subclass define it, no need for `__init__` at all.

I would go a step further and throw an Exception in the base-class just to make sure there's no stray `super()` call on it.

```
import abc

class test(abc.ABC):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        raise NotImplementedException()

class prop_ex(test):
    prop = "THIS WORKS"
```

---

By the way: Your first example already worked for me. The other two don't work because the second approach tries to find a **local variable called `prop`** which doesn't exist and the third approach references **`self` in the class body** - but `self` is only defined in methods/properties of a class, not in the class body.

---

Also this doesn't prevent `__init__` from being overridden in subclasses, any subclass may still modify the `__init__`.

Comment: The doc says `abstractproperty` is deprecated since 3.3. It advises to do with `@property@abstractmethod`

Comment: @Melendowski Thanks. I totally overlooked that. I removed that passage from the answer.

Comment: I must have made a booboo with the first method or something because it works for me now and in fact it is the preferred because the current solution doesn't protect the property to be read-only, which is what I desire.